# delete rows from pandas data frame that contains one of its columns as list , when one of its values match value in another compared list

Tags: dataframe

delete rows from pandas data frame that contains one of its columns as list , when one of its values match value in another compared list column in another data frame.

here is the first data frame column: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTlHJ.jpg)

and the other data frame column is here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zGSi.jpg)

I have tried a lot of codes

Revdf=Revdf.drop(lambda x: [i for i in Revdf.AffiliationHistory if i in Authdf.Affiliations.values], axis=1)

or

Revdf=Revdf[~(Revdf.AffiliationHistory.isin(Authdf.Affiliations.values))]

but these can't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be an easier way, but i wrote a function for it and it works:

```
def remove_row(df1,x1,y1,df2,x2,y2):
    assert type(df1.loc[x1,y1])==list,"type have to be list"
    assert type(df2.loc[x2,y2])==list,"type have to be list"

    flag =False
    l1=df1.loc[x1,y1]
    print(l1)
    l2=df2.loc[x2,y2]
    print(l2)
    for i in l1:
        if i in l2:
            flag=True
            break
    if flag==True:
        return df1.drop(x1)
    else:
        return df1
```

x is the row index, y is the column name, tried it on synthetic data and it works:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,0,0,0,1],
'col2':[[1,2,3,4],0,0,0,0]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,0,0,0],
'col2':[[0,0,0,4],0,0,0]})

remove_row(df1,0,'col2',df2,0,'col2')
```

Also, i think a mistake you're making is this:

```
[1,2,3,4] in [0,1,2,3,4]
```

will return false, because you're asking if the second list contains the first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  what did I need to edit if all the column values are list of values, just as the first element in the second column?